# Wordpress permalink issue - advanced search

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having some issue on my *wordpress site.*
The site url is `http://www.sharedmachine.in/`. 
On the home page there is search option. 
Now the permalink structure right now is like this - `http://www.sharedmachine.in/?p=123`.

Now after clicking the search button, it suppose to redirect to the  'advanced search' page. but it doesn't.

So I changed the permalink structure to custom - `/%postname%/`.

Still it doesn't work.

The URL it should redirect to is

> http://www.sharedmachine.in/advanced-search/?filter_search_type (some filters)

But instead it shows-

> http://www.sharedmachine.in/?filter_search_type (filters)

The page name is not coming in the URL.

Now the code to get url is -

```
$adv_submit=wpestate_get_adv_search_link();
```

and the function -

```
function wpestate_get_adv_search_link(){   
    $pages = get_pages(array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'advanced_search_results.php'
        ));

    if( $pages ){
        $adv_submit = esc_url ( get_permalink( $pages[0]->ID) );
    }else{
        $adv_submit='';
    }

    return $adv_submit;
}
```

If I change the line

```
$adv_submit=wpestate_get_adv_search_link();
```

To

```
$adv_submit='http://www.sharedmachine.in/index.php/advanced-search/';
```

it works.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Thank you @Try for the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aparently the `$pages` variable never gets populated. i would try something like:

```
$page = get_page_by_path('advanced-search');
if ($page) {
    $adv_submit = esc_url ( get_permalink( $page->ID) );
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

in this case you would be looking up the page by its slug as opposed to a page-meta you may or may not have set

Comment: Now this works with /%postname%/ permalink structure. with this structure some of my pages are not working. If I change the structure to default, what change I need to do in above code?

Comment: you shouldn't have to make any changes, but you need to check that wordpress can overwrite your `.htaccess` file, maybe that is the reason why some pages won't work with this structure

Comment: permissions for .htaccess are 644. does it have to be 666?

Comment: 644 is normally required and recommended for .htaccess files.